# Repeating a determined ammount of times inside another ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my sharepoint application, I have a div that is using an ng repeat:

```
<!-- Let's call this div "page" -->
<div class="myPageItem" ng-repeat="item in jsonObject">
    <div class="divStyle">
        <label class="content">{{jsonObject.User}}</label>
    </div>
    <!-- This is the item that is supposed to be repeated 3 times inside here -->
    <!-- Let's call this other "page item" -->
    <!-- this must be repeated 3 times for each page, with 3 different names on each one -->
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated>
       <label id="bla">{{item.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JsonObject would look like this:

```
jsonObject:
[ 
  { User       : 'JohnSpartan' },
  { SomeThing  : 'SomeData'    },
  { UserFlag   : '1337'        },
  { Ship       : 'BSG-75'      },
  { WeaponList : [{"name":"1337-b"},{"name":"Roflcopter"},{"name":"Shazam"},{"name":"theb33f"]}
]
```

So, each *page* have to contain each one 3 *page items*. Each page has to have unique 3 page items, because this is used at our pagination system, and each *page* is a unique page that's being generated using that class.

I tried ng-repeat-start to generate for each page unique 3 pageItems, but I think it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I could do it with C# on server side, but I'm looking for a more pratical solution.
I tried also [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo), but I don't exactly see how can I use it in my situation.

Some have already answered, but as I said above, I already tried limitTo, and it does not work in my case, as it will repeat the same 3 *page items* for each *page*.

Can I do that with filters? Accordlingy to some answers, I can. But I really wanted a really simple solution. Does angular don't have anything that can slice my object, without needing of a filter to do so?

I guess I can explain better with the expected result.
The result could be something like this:

```
<div class="myPageItem">
    <div class="divStyle">
         <label class="content">JohnSpartan</label>
    </div>
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated>
        <label>1337-b</label>
    </div>
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated>
        <label>Roflcopter</label>
    </div>
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated>
        <label>Shazam</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="myPageItem">
    <div class="divStyle">
         <label class="content">JohnSpartan</label>
    </div>
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated>
        <label>theb33f</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean items may have say 10 objects and you just want to display only 3(or X) of them?

Comment: Only 3 of them for each that div with the class "myPageItem". If I had 10, for instance, I wanted to show 4 myPageItem div's, 3 with 3 itemToBeRepeated and 1 with only one itemToBeRepeated.

Comment: If this is really 3 items, my advise it to simply add 3 sub-items, the rendering will be faster this way. Another option is to prepare the model from the controller with the repetition already in. The last option is to add `ng-repeat="subItem in [0,1,2]"` into your itemToBeRepeated tag. Of course if your item have the subItems array you can use `subItem in item.subItems`

Comment: Why cant you just model your data accordingly to a 2d array.

Comment: @FlavienVolken subItem in [0,1,2] - that would be the position in the elements? Won't that cause the second PageItem to also repeat the same subItems from the previous pageItem?

Comment: @Malavos I added an answer with a Plunker example. Basically you should rely on the controller to prepare the data to display, not on  the view (even if it might be possible). Preparing the data, means telling for example your M item will only have N subItems

Comment: @FlavienVolken I made a small edit. This data is returned from the client database; I did not want to operate this data, specially in Javascript. If I have to do so, I wanted to do it in C#. To avoid that, that was why I was looking for the simpler solution possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two ng-repeats. One iterates the pages and the other one iterates the items for each page. You can limit the number of items to 3.

```
<div class="myPageItem" ng-repeat="page in pages">
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated" ng-repeat="item in page.items | limitTo: 3">
       <label id="bla">{{item.Content}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[UPDATE] Your question is not providing enough information. For starters what is inside item.Content and how do you want to break it into different pieces? According to your question your code looks like this:

```
<!-- This is the item that is supposed to be repeated 3 times inside here -->
<!-- Let's call this other "page item" -->
<div class="itemToBeRepeated>
   <label id="bla">{{item.Content}}</label>
</div>
```

This will show one content per page content for all repetitions of pages. that is because for all three you are showing the same item.Content. If you want them to be different you need to tell us more about what is inside item.Content and how do you want to show in different pages. My guts tell me that you are doing this wrong by putting all of the page data in one Content. You should slice the content into multiple objects and render each object separately in each div.

My answer was exactly meant to show different item content for each page. The data needs to be paginated.sliced into multiple objects in array for you to be able to show distinct contents in each div. This is how to prepare the data to be different in each div:

```
$scope.pages = 
[
  {
    items:
    [ 
      { Content: 'Page1-Item1' },
      { Content: 'Page1-Item2' },
      { Content: 'Page1-Item3' }
    ]
  },
  {
    items:
    [ 
      { Content: 'Page2-Item1'},
      { Content: 'Page2-Item2'},
      { Content: 'Page2-Item3'}
    ]
  }
];
```

The rendered Html will be something like this:

```
<div class="myPageItem">
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated">
       <label id="bla">Page1-Item1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated">
       <label id="bla">Page1-Item2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated">
       <label id="bla">Page1-Item3</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="myPageItem">
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated">
       <label id="bla">Page2-Item1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated">
       <label id="bla">Page2-Item2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated">
       <label id="bla">Page2-Item3</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is limitTo filter that already exists in angular

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemToBeRepeated | limitTo: 3">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: MKhanal, thanks for answering, but a question. Won't the next div to be repeated have the same 3 items? Or will each one have 3 different items?

Comment: They will have the same items with one control in your hand. If you supply positive value to filter, top 3 ones are used. If you use negative value i.e. -3 then bottom 3 are used. If you want random then I would suggest you to write a new filter implementation. The filter would not be stateless if you want it to remember the last position in the list everytime you want to repeat on it. I highly advise against stateful. You can create a filter that takes how many you want to display and starting at what index.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should be preparing the data into a controller, then the view will be displaying what the controller prepared. This is the good practice

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = 
  [
  {"subItems":[{"name":"a"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"}]},
  {"subItems":[{"name":"d"},{"name":"e"},{"name":"f"}]},
  {"subItems":[{"name":"g"},{"name":"h"},{"name":"i"}]},
  ]
});
```

And the html (view) part

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS: Inline Edit</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div class="myPageItem" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <!-- This is the item that is supposed to be repeated 3 times inside here -->

    <div class="itemToBeRepeated" ng-repeat="subItem in item.subItems">
       <label id="bla">{{subItem.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/v6mYosIAAvbmBOlr1flV?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like :

```
<div class="myPageItem" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
    <!-- This is the item that is supposed to be repeated 3 times inside here -->
    <div class="itemToBeRepeated" ng-show="$index < 3">
       <label id="bla">{{item.Content}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I think you would be better to use a filter that slices the items array.

Comment: What will happen with the next myPageItem on this case? Will it render the first three items?

Comment: oh, you are right, in this case you'll have an empty myPageItem for each item after the third.  Not a good solution.  But using a filter would work better : <div class="myPageItem" ng-repeat="item in items | myFilter:3">

Comment: I think I will do that way. Do you have any tutorial on filters that you could recommend? Or a JS fiddle example?

Comment: Thanks to MKhanal for his answer, pointing to the limitTo filter that already exist in angular.  I did not know that.