# Slice by Index with increment

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, list, slice

I have something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="atma in abc">
   <li ng-repeat="atma in abc.slice(0,3)"><span>{{$index+1}} - {{atma.weapon}} </span></li>
</div>
```

I wanted to slice these results at, each div repeat, each time being used the 3 items from index.

So I would start with the first div showing the weapons ranging from 1 to 3.
The second one would have elements from 4 to 6.
And so on.

Can I use $index or something like that on my slice?

Ps.: This question came from trying my best on [this question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533682/repeating-a-determined-ammount-of-times-inside-another-ng-repeat)
I'm still having some trouble, but I made another question based on what I could do with slice.

Comment: `li` cannot be within a `div`. It is invalid html. And yes you can use $index

Comment: @PSL Sorry, there was a ul before with fixed elements, I removed it to get a cleared code. Should I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st:

```
<div ng-repeat="atma in data">
   <ul ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">
       <li><span>{{data[$index]}} </span>
       </li>
       <li ng-if="$index+ 1 < data.length"><span>{{data[$index+1]}} </span>
       </li>
       <li ng-if="$index+ 2 < data.length"><span>{{data[$index+2]}} </span>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

2nd:

```
<div ng-repeat="atma in data">
   <ul ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" ng-init="tmp = data.slice($index, $index + 3)">
       <li ng-repeat="atma1 in tmp"><span>{{atma1}}</span>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Uo1ROo549swNorzixTi3?p=preview

Comment: Forgot to accept; Done. The second solution worked really, really well. Finally I have found the solution that would work with pure angular.